# How to unit test an Angular 1 controller that contains DOM/jquery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

When using jasmine, I can't seem to test a function that has a jquery selector or `document.getElementById` in it. Is there a better strategy here? I normally do not put selectors in angular code, however this is a workaround.

In the function I'm testing:

```
this.scope.login = () => {

 ($('#login-form')[0] as HTMLFormElement).submit(); 
 // or even 
 document.getElementById('login-form').submit(); // this is a workaround for browser auto-complete, I normally would not have selectors in angular code.
}
```

I get

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$('#login-form')[0].submit')

I've tried "mocking by spying," using spyOn to try to mock the jquery selector function and return a fake element... but doesn't seem to work, or I'm not doing it right.

My spec loads the template (logs ok). Element is also defined and seems to be a valid angular-compiled element.

```
describe('Nav Controller Spec', function() {

beforeEach(function() {
  angular.mock.module('App');

  inject(function(_$controller_, $rootScope, _userModel_, _$q_, _$httpBackend_, $templateCache, _$compile_) {

    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $q = _$q_;
    $compile = _$compile_;
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    deferred = _$q_.defer();

    html = $templateCache.get('main/components/login/login.tpl.html');
    var el = angular.element( html );
    element = $compile( el )(scope); //element is valid and works

    controller = _$controller_;
    userModel = _userModel_;

    scope.userModel = userModel;

    // tried this... still get error
    spyOn($.fn, 'val').and.returnValue('<form></form>');

    //if i change to 'init' or 'find', i get 'undefined is not a constructor'
    spyOn($.fn, 'init').and.returnValue('<form></form>');

    ctrl = controller('loginController', { $scope: scope, $element: element });

    $rootScope.$digest();
  });

});

it('should login and change the status', function(){
   spyOn(  ctrl.scope.userModel, 'login' ).and.callThrough();
   ctrl.scope.formType = 'login';
   ctrl.scope.login(); //fails
   expect( ctrl.scope.userModel.login ).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

As a last resort, i tried the following with `document.getElementById('login-form')` in the controller. However, I get `TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'document.getElementById('login-form').submit()')`

```
  var mockElement = {
    id:"login-form",
    parentNode:true
  };
  var document_getElementById = document.getElementById;
  var spy = spyOn(document, "getElementById").and.callFake(function(id){
    if(id===mockElement.id){
      return mockElement;
    }
    return document_getElementById(id);
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, this works. You will want to stub/spy with `document.getElementById` since that's what jquery uses under the hood.  I only had forgotten to stub the `submit` function. I didn't realize this because jasmine's wrapped errors are so meaningless.

```
      var mockElement = {
        id:"login-form",
        parentNode:true,
         submit:function(){
           return 'cheese';
         }
      };
      var document_getElementById = document.getElementById;
      var spy = spyOn(document, "getElementById").and.callFake(function(id){
        if(id===mockElement.id){
          return mockElement;
        }
        return document_getElementById(id);
      });
```